# Optimal Kernel Size for Lanczos resampling

Tags: mathematical-statistics, kernel-smoothing

The kernel for Lanczos resampling is defined by

$$K(u) = \frac{a \sin(\pi u) \sin(\pi u/a)}{\pi^2u^2}.$$

How does one go about finding a value of $a$ to minimize the mean squared error, $\text{MSE} = b^2 + \sigma^2$? Is there at least a scaling relationship with size of the data set, $n$, as there is with Gaussian kernels?

Note: I don't know if will matter, but let's assume a strictly positive distribution.